# Javascript: can't load JSON file from localhost

Tags: javascript, json, localhost

I'm currently working through the book "Head first HTML5 programming". I want to load the content of a file named `sales.json` from a web server on my own machine. I used wampserver for this.

In the folder `wamp/www/gumball/` I put all relevant `.html`, `.js` and `.css` files, and also the `sales.json` file.

My JavaScript code is very simple:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var url = "http://localhost/gumball/sales.json";
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("GET", url);
    request.onload = function() {
        if (request.status == 200) {
            updateSales(request.responseText);
        }
    };
    request.send(null);
}

function updateSales(responseText) {
    var salesDiv = document.getElementById("sales");
    salesDiv.innerHTML = responseText;
}
```

This doesn't do anything! Typing the link: `http://localhost/gumball/sales.json` in my browser opens the right file, so the link should be correct. Even when using the `.js` files that come with the book (with a finished version of the application I'm trying to make), nothing loads.

Testing with alert statements tells me the `request.onload` event never happens. I'm clueless as to why this is the case.

A fact I don't quite understand yet: when I type: `http://localhost/gumball/sales.json:` in my browser (I added a colon at the end of the link), I get a 403 Forbidden error! Why does this happen? Does this have something to do with my problem?

Comment: How do you open the initial file ? You must open it through `http://localhost/...`, not `file://`

Comment: What URL are you loading _from_?

Comment: What do you mean? You can see the way I try to reach the file in my code, and typing http://localhost/gumball/sales.json in the browser returns the desired file. So I'm not opening it from file://. When I take the wamp server offline, the link I use doesn't work.

Comment: @Kappie001 — dystroy and SLaks are asking how you open the **HTML** document, not the JSON document.

Comment: @Kappie001 have you receive any errors in console?

Comment: What messages are reported in the JavaScript console of your browser?

Comment: @SLaks, what do you mean? Newbie here!

Comment: @Kappie001: The HTML file that you're running the JS in. What URL does it have? (what is in the address bar?)

Comment: @Kappie001 We all think about the same origin policy : a HTML file opened with an origin can't open a js file with a different origin unless you set the relevant CORS headers.

Comment: I open html document with firefox. What are errors in console? Opening the javascript console in firefox (which I have never done before) doesn't report any errors at first glance.

Comment: the html file url:
file:///C:/wamp/www/gumball/gumball.html
I think I understand what you guys are aiming at... this also needs to be ran from the server, correct?

Comment: @Kappie001 — How do you open the HTML document with Firefox? Do you type `http://localhost/etc/etc` into the address bar? Reload the page while the console is open.

Comment: @Kappie001 — That is your problem. Don't develop using `file:///` URIs, load the HTML document from your webserver.

Comment: It's working, I wasn't opening the html file from the wamp server!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I open html document with firefox

Your HTML document must be open with a URL in `http://`, not `file://`, if you want it to be able to open in javascript another document, unless the second document is served with relevant [CORS headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS).

This is due to [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

As you have a local WAMP server, there is no problem : simply open your file using a `http://` URL like you do for your JSON file.

Comment: Yes, it's working. I totally understand now. Thanks for the quick replies!