# IE 11 - unable to load json file in D3 on local computer - "SCRIPT 5 Access is Denied" error due to Same Origin Policy

Tags: javascript, json, internet-explorer, d3.js

I get below error when trying to load this [D3](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339184) in Internet Explorer 11 on Windows 7:

```
SCRIPT 5 : Access is denied
d3.min.js, Line: 1, Column: 10922
```

Researching the error, [msdn says](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dn887953(v=vs.94).aspx), it is due to Same-Origin Policy. But I saved all files - [d3.min.js](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js) , [flare.json](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/raw/4063550/flare.json) and [html file](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=qDV7VFFh) - locally in the same directory.
I also lowered Security setting on all zones, and added `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />` , but no luck.

It works fine on Firefox & Chrome though.
It also works fine on IE if I include the content of json within the html as a javascript variable like `var data = {"name":"flare",...}` , but not when reading from an external .json file.

I guess this is impossible to do in IE.. ?

**EDIT-SOLUTION**: The problem was because I was trying to do this on my local computer. Once I uploaded the files to a Sharepoint website, it opened fine.

Comment: Are you hosting the files on a web server or you access the HTML from browser with file://?

Comment: i'm using file:// to test it on my local PC

Comment: This doesn't work. Read my answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript: can't load JSON file from localhost](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18559107/javascript-cant-load-json-file-from-localhost)

Answer (score 1):

If you access the HTML file directly with the browser with `file://` this error is because the access is restricted to the same protocol, host and port. With AJAX always you've to access the file via HTTP(S) and `d3.json()` uses AJAX to load the JSON file. If the JSON is hosted on other domain the error is probably because CORS restriction on the other side.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Comment: OK, I put the directory on a web server, created an IIS application, changed the paths to http:// and accessed it remotely. The Access denied error is gone, but now I get this error - *object XMLHttpRequest* on IE11 and *object XDomainRequeston* IE 9

Comment: I was able to get it to work on Sharepoint website instead of regular IIS. I copied all js,json,css to the same folder, and accessed them in the html by simply giving file name "d3.js", or "flare.json", without any file:// or http:// qualifiers in front.